# Split on line based on a character

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to solve the problem below, but struggling to find something that works.

I have a large text file, 2 lines shown as an example:

```
TEST ABCXYZ:1234  PNT = 543210
TEST ABCXYZ:1256  PNT = 543233
```

I want to end up with

```
TEST ABCXYZ:1234
PNT = 543210
TEST ABCXYZ:1256
PNT = 543233
```

So, I have tried delimiting on spaceP but that always carries the P to the next line. I have also tried macros but not familiar with that method.

Comment: Looks like the delimiter would be `  P` (space space P) based on the 2 sample lines

Answer (score 0):

Lets say line by line ends with e.g. `PNT = 543210` you'd go through following steps (quick and dirty solution, make a save copy of your file first):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(PNT = [0-9]{6}$)`
- Replace with: `\r\n\r\n\1\r\n`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk!)

results in:

[image]

Please note - MacOS, by default, uses a single carriage return (`<CR>`), represented as `\r`. Unix uses a single linefeed (`<LF>`), `\n`. Windows uses both, creating a (`<CRLF>`) combination, `\r\n`.

If necessary you have to adapt this for your operating system and your requirements.

If you want to delete the spaces before PNT, you can use the following alternative:

- Find what: `(\ \ )(PNT = [0-9]{6}$)`
- Replace with: `\r\n\r\n\2\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+(?=PNT\h+=\h+\d+)`
- Replace with: `\n` OR `\r\n` depending on platform
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    PNT             # literally
    \h+=\h+         # equal sign suround by spaces
    \d+             # 1 or more digits
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]